# Extract substring from first column

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a large text file with 2 columns. The first column is large and complicated, but contains a `name="..."` portion. The second column is just a number.

How can I produce a text file such that the first column contains ONLY the name, but the second column stays the same and shows the number? Basically, I want to extract a substring from the first column only AND have the 2nd column stay unaltered.

Sample data:

```
application{id="1821", name="app-name_01"} 0
application{id="1822", name="myapp-02", optionalFlag="false"} 1
application{id="1823", optionalFlag="false", name="app_name_public"} 3
...
```

So the result file would be something like this

```
app-name_01     0
myapp-02        1
app_name_public 3
...
```

Comment: Are the lines similar or can the name be anywhere in that column? Show some sample data.

Comment: The name can be anywhere in that column, so I need to match it using a regular expression such as `name="([a-zA-Z0-9_-])"`, with the parens meaning capture this part in a group

Comment: You've shown the result, but please show sample input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your actual Input_file is same as the shown sample then following code may help you in same.

```
awk '{sub(/.*name=\"/,"");sub(/\".* /," ")} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
app-name_01 0
myapp-02 1
app_name_public 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk`

```
$ awk 'match($0,/name="([^"]*)"/,a){print a[1],$NF}' infile
app-name_01 0
myapp-02 1
app_name_public 3
```

Non-Gawk

```
awk 'match($0,/name="([^"]*)"/){t=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/name=|"/,"",t);print t,$NF}' infile
app-name_01 0
myapp-02 1
app_name_public 3
```

Input:

```
$ cat infile
application{id="1821", name="app-name_01"} 0
application{id="1822", name="myapp-02", optionalFlag="false"} 1
application{id="1823", optionalFlag="false", name="app_name_public"} 3
...
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work on my real data, which is more complicated. The sample data was REALLY basic, but giving sample data that exactly matches the real structure is almost impossible. Thanks and sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `sed` solution:

```
sed -r 's/.*name="([^"]+).* ([0-9]+)$/\1 \2/g' Input_file
```

Explanation:

With the parantheses your store in groups what's inbetween.
First group is everything after `name="` till the first `"`. `[^"]` means "not a double-quote".
Second group is simply "one or more numbers at the end of the line preceeded with a space".